# want to get multiple values from dropdown after adding script tag in html page it stop working or using select and script tag togetherit stop working

Tags: javascript, python, django

This is my load clients function from where I pass value to clients.html page
views.py

```
def load_clients(request):
    CPA_id = request.GET.get('CPA_id')
    clients = CPA_Client.objects.filter(CPA_id=CPA_id)
    return render(request, 'crm/clients_dropdown_list_options.html', {"clients": clients})
        # return JsonResponse(list(cities.values('id', 'name')), safe=False
client.html
<select id="ddselect" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control">
  <option value="----">------</option>
  {% for Client_of_CPA in clients %}
  <option value="{{ Client_of_CPA.pk }}">{{ Client_of_CPA.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

In this code i am getting my output but need to select multiple values from a dropdown thats why i want to add some functionality of bootstrap jquery due to which i need script tag.
After adding script tag page stop working

This is my whole code in html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#ddselect').multiselect(
          {
           nonSelectedText: 'Select Framework',
          enableFiltering: true,
          enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
          closeOnSelect:false,
          });
      
        
      });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 
    <select id="ddselect" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control">
  <option value="----">------</option>
  {% for Client_of_CPA in clients %}
  <option value="{{ Client_of_CPA.pk }}">{{ Client_of_CPA.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are calling it  via Ajax ? and is it a partial html ?

Comment: yes i am calling it via Ajax and as now i am getting dropdown list bt after adding script and select tag together it stop working

Comment: could you please show your whole template where you have that script  ?

Comment: i have added the entire code please check it

Comment: you have to import jquery in the head of your page.

Comment: imported jquery js css bootstrap but nothing worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.